# Calling submethod from Parent in ObjectiveC (IOS6)

Tags: objective-c, methods, subclass

SquareGeo, TriangleGeo is drived from Geo class.
Each of SquareGeo, TriangleGeo classes have drawMe methods with same parameters but different content.

I wantto call drawMe from the base class is Geo
but, issue Navigator says me a warning:

```
"Instance method '-drawMe' not found (return type defaults to 'id')"
```

in conclusion:
How can I call a method from Parent that is only defined all its child Classes.

shall I avoid warning ? should I use protocols ?
looking something like this:

```
[sub drawMe]; //not super
```

any idea ?  (please do not refer me to java examples.only objectC knowhow)

Comment: Its just a warning. If it really bothers you then create a formal protocol (aka declare the method on the parent class). Of course, if you decide ***not*** too declare a formal protocol, then its highly recommended that you check that your object actually responds to the `drawMe` method before calling it.

Comment: so you mean <protocol> is the magical key that what Im looking for ?

Comment: It seems odd to add a protocol here. The base class knows it is going to call a method with `self` being the receiver therefore no other class can really make use of this protocol in this context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to overcome this is to provide an empty implementation in the parent class.

If you want to ensure that subclasses do provide their own implementation then you can add an exception to the base class' method

```
@implementation Base

- (void)drawMe;
{
  [NSException raise:NSInternalInconsistencyException 
        format:@"You must override %@ in a subclass", NSStringFromSelector(_cmd)];
}
```

Comment: isnt there an abstract method definition in objectiveC? o.h.n.o

Comment: IIRC this is the closest you can get

Comment: if we define drawMe with Exception raiser in subclass (as you mentioned)
will it call overriden ? or the base class's methods ?

I think,overrides really overrides. right?so this method seems applicable and closest solution.

Comment: If I make a subclass of `Base` and implement `drawMe` then the subclasses implementation will be used. Make sure you do not call `[super drawMe];` in the subclass or you will call back to the super implementation and throw an exception

Answer (score 1):

Thats the beautiful thing about inheritance, you declare the method in the parent, and implement it in the children, and the underlying system handles calling the "correct" version of the method depending on what type of class the instance actually is.

Comment: yes. drawMe will be defined with protocol.
so, a needle to override it.to be sure is callable back from the superclass

otherwise I have to define repeately same method for each of subclasses; which uses drawMe in superclass.

Comment: If you define it in a protocol, make sure the parent class implements that protocol, otherwise, declare the method in the parent class, not a protocol

Comment: so can I avoid warnings ?
because I m sure the method is defined in superclasses

Comment: Yes, declare it in the parent class, create a blank implementation, or an exception raising implementation as Paul.s shows in his answer, and voila, no more warnings.  If you're still getting warnings, then include some of your class declarations in your question